# Callbacks don't fire in JQuery Mobile multi-page

Tags: ios, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm pulling my hair out on this one..I have a single .html page to represent my mobile app's homepage. In that same html page I have a page defined to be a login screen. The logic to display the login screen works just fine...my problem is that I have a login function with the following signature...

```
ajaxLogin(credentials, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    $.ajax({
            url: SERVER_API + '/login',
            data: credentials,
            type: 'post',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
            },
            always: function () {
                console.log('always');
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            },
            done: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log('login: ok'); //< -- This never fires but I can see that the server returned a 200 in Safari's developer menu
                successCallback();
            },
            fail: function (request, error) {
                failureCallback(); // <-- This function is never executed when I send bad login info. But again, the server is returning an error status code
            }
        });
}
```

I assumed this would be pretty straightforward...Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *beforeSend* function is part of the jQuery Ajax settings jQuery.ajax( [settings ] ). However *always*, *done* and *fail* are promise methods of the jqXHR object. In your example you have used *always*, *done* and *fail* as settings which is not correct.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://.....",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // code
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    // do something
});
```

You can find more information in the [jQ Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for "success" and "error", ie:

```
ajaxLogin(credentials, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: SERVER_API + '/login',
        data: credentials,
        type: 'post',
        async: true,
        success: successCallback,
        error:  failureCallback
    });
}
```

And then you can take care of your success/failure in the original call to this function:

```
ajaxLogin(
    credentialsData, //data you're passing to the function
    function (data)
    {
        //stuff to do on success
    },
    function (jqXHR, statusText, errorThrown)
    {
        //stuff to do on failure
    }
);
```